# Will Ruby On Rails 4 set by defaut config.active_record.whitelist_attributes to true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Did RoR4 will set by default config.active_record.whitelist_attributes to true and some other securities values ?

Now I think RoR is enough simplified to integrates this kinds of constraints for securities reasons.

Thanks

Comment: Probably yes. Too early to say for sure.

Comment: Asking a question about the future is unlikely to have a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now, yes -- check it out:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/application.rb#L57

```
# Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
# This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
# in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
# parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
<%= comment_if :skip_active_record %>config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

Answer (score 3):

...and it's [gone](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d695fdbd1181a002595ae2d80e2ee6955801b602). This is likely going to stay given Rails 4 has abstracted `attr_accessible` into a gem.